# Issues while untaring tarball with acl

Tags: linux, solaris, tar, access-control-lists

I am getting an error “Unknown file type 'A', extracted as normal file” while un-taring a set of files which has acl permissions set.

I had created the tar file in Solaris with `tar -cpfv Tarfilename.tar directory`. If I un-tar with `tar xvpf Tarfilename.tar`, it works great in Solaris. I had copied the tar file to Linux and tried to untar using `tar xvpf`, it throws the warning “Unknown file type 'A', extracted as normal file” and created files without ACL permissions.

`tar --version` in Linux: `tar (GNU tar) 1.15.1`

Comment: Please use punctuation between sentences. Your question was very hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Solaris uses NFSv4 ACLs while Linux uses POSIX ACLs. They are not directly compatible.

While Linux is (naturally) using `gnu-tar`, as you pointed out, I suspect that on Solaris you're using Solaris' native `tar`.

According to the Solaris `tar(1)` man page:

> p
>
> Restore the named files to  their  original  modes,  and
>   ACLs  if applicable, ignoring the present umask(1). This
>   is the default behavior if invoked  as  super-user  with
>   the  x function letter specified. If super-user, SETUID,
>   and sticky information are also extracted, and files are
>   restored  with  their  original  owners and permissions,
>   rather than owned by root. When this  function  modifier
>   is  used  with  the  c function, ACLs are created in the
>   tarfile along with other information. **Errors occur  when
>   a tarfile with ACLs is extracted by previous versions of
>   tar.**

You should use `gnu-tar` on Solaris if you're using the `-p` flag to preserve permissions and the tar will be extracted on a Linux system.

If you're using Solaris 11, install the `gnu-tar` package which will be located in `/usr/gnu/bin/tar` or `/usr/gnu/bin/gtar`. If you're using a release earlier than Solaris 11 you'll need to get `gnu-tar` from Sun FreeWare (which may be available on your Solaris Companion CD).

Comment: Thanks bahamat, tar operations works fine in Solaris 9. I had created tarball using tar -p but when I extract it in Linux, I am facing issues. I did a scp getfacl | setfacl finally.